# How to associate the ObjectId of the parent schema to the child schema in the same transaction?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs, mongoose-schema

I have two types of entities, `users` and `families`, with a many-to-one relationship between families and users, so one family can have many users but one user will only have one family. I attempted to create a Mongo schema that tries to achieve this relationship, but not sure if this is the right way to do it.

I have a button on my HTML page that when clicked, will generate a family code and also create a new family attribute for the family entity. However, I'm unable to connect that newly generated `family.ObjectId` to the user's familyid attribute in the user entity.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**My Models:**

**Family Model:**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var shortid = require('shortid');
//Set Schema
var familySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    individuals: [{
           type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
           ref: "User"
        }],
    familyCode: {
            type: String,
            'default': shortid.generate
    }
});

//setup and export the model
module.exports = mongoose.model("Family", familySchema);
```

**Users Model:**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:   String,
    password:   String,
    image:      String,
    firstName:  String,
    lastName:   String,
    accountid:  String,
    isAdmin:    {type: Boolean, default: false},
    userlabel: String,
    familyid:
        { type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Family"}
         });

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

**My Route:**

```
router.post("/familySetup", function(req, res){
    if(!req.body.familyid){
        var familyCode = shortid.generate();
        console.log(familyCode);
        // var individuals = {id:req.user._id}
        var newFamily = {familyCode:familyCode};

        Family.create(newFamily, function(err, newFamily){
            if(err){
                req.flash("error", "something seems to have gone amiss. Please try again.")
                console.log(err);
                res.redirect("home")
            }else{
                var updatedUser = {familyid:newFamily._id}
                console.log(updatedUser);
                User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.user_id, updatedUser, function(req, res){
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }else{
                          //redirect to index
                        res.redirect("/familySetup");                    
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }else{
        alert("You already have a family account");
        res.redirect("back");
    }
});
```

Based on the error I get, I am able to create a `familyCode` and am able to create the variable, `updatedUser`. But it does not update the user with the new attribute. This is the error when I run the code:

```
ByJyRqb_Z
{ familyid: 59941dd6589f9a1c14a36550 }
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'redirect' of null
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/mbswalay/routes/family.js:44:28
    at Query.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/mbswalay/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3755:16)
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/mbswalay/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:277:21
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/mbswalay/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:131:16
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:436:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:365:13)
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be an error of mongodb, it's related to the route configuration, which seems make the response object to be null

Answer (score 0):

```
User.updateOne(
    { _id: req.params.user_id },
    { $set: { familyid: newFamily._id } }
  )
```

You have to set the value of an attribute using `$set` operator.